# resolv.conf Ordering of Nameserver Responses

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind, nameservers, dnsmasq

When `dig`ing URL's there was a conversation that came up wherein an individual claimed the order in which NS are selected from `resolv.conf` is random or merely non-deterministic.

I was skeptical so ran a simulation. I spin up 3 BIND9 Ubuntu 17 boxes and mapped them in my `resolv.conf` file on a jumpbox:

```
# resolv.conf on jumpbox
nameserver 10.0.215.157 #dns1
nameserver 10.0.3.163   #dns2
nameserver 10.0.22.32   #dns3
```

I then dig from my jumpbox:
`dig www.amazon.com` and I get a response I'd expect:

```
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5308
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 1

    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;amazon.com.                    IN      A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    amazon.com.             25      IN      A       205.251.242.103
    amazon.com.             25      IN      A       176.32.98.166
    amazon.com.             25      IN      A       176.32.103.205

    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    .                       86618   IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
    .                       86618   IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.

    ;; Query time: 0 msec
    ;; SERVER: 10.0.215.157#53(10.0.215.157)
    ;; WHEN: Mon Jul 02 21:44:07 EDT 2018
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 298
```

I dig several times and each time it goes to **#dns1**.  I `systemctl stop bind9`on **#dns1** and as expected, my query is handled by **#dns2**.

I `systemctl start bind9` on **#dns1** and my dig is handled by **dns1**.

So what I am seeing every step of the way is that the order in which the nameservers are listed in the `resolv.conf` file is the order in which they will be selected when choosing the nameserver.

which seems to be reinforced by this entry from the Manpage `resolv.conf` file:

```
   nameserver Name server IP address
          Internet address of a  name  server  that  the  resolver  should
          query,  either  an  IPv4  address  (in dot notation), or an IPv6
          address in colon (and possibly dot) notation as  per  RFC  2373.
          Up  to  MAXNS  (currently 3, see <resolv.h>) name servers may be
          listed, one per keyword.  If there  are  multiple  servers,  the
          resolver  library  queries  them  in  the  order  listed.  If no
          nameserver entries are present, the default is to use  the  name
          server  on  the  local machine.  (The algorithm used is to try a
          name server, and if the query times out, try the next, until out
          of name servers, then repeat trying all the name servers until a
          maximum number of retries are made.)
```

Is there something I'm missing? I am not an expert when it comes to DNS but struggling to see where my logic may be flawed.

Could it be that the way systemd writes the `resolv.conf` file is what makes it random?

This was the article referenced as to the natural shuffling behavior of recursors: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5755

Is the selection of recursors actually random behavior for Ubuntu >= 17

Comment: Github issue seemed to be around the caching behavior of selecting last known working recursors, not random selection:

**Quote**
`This is what happens. However, in contrast to classic nss-dns we have memory: when we noticed that a DNS server didn't respond or returned some failure, or for some other reason wasn't working for us, and we skip to the next, then we remember that and the next lookup is attempted with the new one. If that one fails too, then we'll skip to the next one and the next one and so on, until we reach the end of the list and start from the beginning of the list again.`

Comment: The manual is clear: the order in the file is taken into account, only the first nameserver is queried except if it does not reply then the second get queried and so on. This is redone per query. Your conversation was maybe about the NS records in some given DNS responses: in that case indeed DNS records are sets so they are not ordered. In most cases if you do `dig NS something` you will get a different order of records each time.